# Stored Procedures and Functions Parametere Type Error

Tags: excel, stored-procedures, plsql

I am making reports on Excel file, with Database using ODBC connection type. I have write a SQL function with some parameters => Date, Number, Varchar, Varchar, Varchar.

When I am making a connection in excel and give the syntax as :
{CALL mystoredProc(?,?,?,?,?)}

Putting this connection in my Excel sheet Cell, it will ask for Parameters. Here the problem occured. I have provided 5 parameters but It will ask for six. Second thing, First Parameter accept all number or varchar. !!! and the next four will oke but last one always said Invalid Parameter Type.

I don't understand what to do. Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are dealing with a function. You have 5 in parameters and the 6th parameter is the result, you can:
Overload the function and make it a procedure or try leaving first or last parameter in blank.

The last parameter may be the result parameter thats why its saying you that is invalid.

Comment: I am using something like that it running in Excel successfully but not giving me the output. Cell displaying "ExternalData_1"

Comment: Query I am using is : declare ret_val Number; BEGIN ret_val := sql_function_name(param1, param2,...); END;